# How to pass from seconds to time

Tags: mysql, time

How can I pass from seconds to time on mysql?

the date format of out is hh:mm:ss.ms

Sorry. I need for example 0.98 sec -> 00:00:00.980; With sec_to_tiem return 00:00:01.

thanks.

I have implemeted of this way:

```
select concat(if(floor(seconds/(60 * 60)) = 0,'00',lpad(floor(seconds/(60 * 60)),2,'0')), 
':',
if(floor(seconds/60) = 0,'00',lpad(floor(seconds / 60),2,'0')), 
':',
seconds % 60)
```

but it have to exist other way more efficient

other way:

```
CONCAT(lpad(floor(seconds / 3600), 2, '0'), ':', 
      lpad(floor(seconds / 60), 2, '0'), ':',
      lpad(floor(seconds  % 60), 2, '0'), '.', 
      lpad(SUBSTRING_INDEX((seconds * 1000) % 1000, '.', 1), 3, '0'))
```

Comment: what's the real question here?

Comment: Did you read the Mysql manual? There is a whole page about date and time functions...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAKETIME (<yourseconds>/(60*24), <yourseconds>/60, <yourseconds>%60)
```

or with format

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT( MAKETIME( <yourseconds>/ ( 60 *24 ) , <yourseconds>/60, <yourseconds>%60 ) ,  '%T.%f' )
```